# Displaying a value only if another cell has a value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to display an empty box (HTML entity `&#9633` □ or any other similar box will do) in Excel in a cell if and only if another cell has a value.

I've tried `=IF(ISBLANK(C8),,□)`, but that gives me an Invalid Name Error. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Check the syntax for the IF function. The second argument is the result if the first argument is true, the third argument is the result if the first argument is false. 
So `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"","□")` will display the empty string if the cell B1 is blank, or the square box (note the quote marks) if not blank. Check also functions ISNUMBER etc instead of ISBLANK if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You must put quotes around your box:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C8),,"□")
```

The following ones also work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C8),"","□")

=IF(C8="","□",)

=IF(C8="","□","")
```